# Azure Virtual Machine: slow CPU-bound HtmlAgilityPack operation processing

Tags: .net, performance, azure, html-agility-pack

I've got a performance trouble moving my WinForms app from local machine to Windows Azure Virtual Machine.
The application is a multithreaded HTML parser. It uses a third-party HtmlAgilityPack.dll. This library is used for creating a DOM-tree from HTML like here(VB.NET code):

```
Dim HtmlAgilityPackDoc As New HtmlDocument
HtmlAgilityPackDoc.LoadHtml(_html)
```

Then we can parse it with other methods.
`.LoadHtml` is a CPU-bound method.

The problem is that this method works extremely much slowly on Azure VM(A4 8-Core) then on local machine (notebook with cheap Core i5-3317U CPU).
Another CPU-bound work complete faster on Azure VM(I have tried other methods, clear circles). CPU benchmarks show that Azure VM much more powerful. I just can get how can it happen. Any ideas what can be the reason?

Comment: You will have to run the code under a profiler to see what is going on.  It's very hard to guess based on your description.  If I had to make a guess you are probably doing some file IO as part of this processing and those calls are taking longer than on your machine.

Comment: @AndreVa, I've tried another third-party library to replace HtmlAgilityPack.dll. It works slower on Azure VM too. So both of referenced libraries works slower. Looks like you're wright. But I can't get what IO-operations happens. Is HDD IO-operation perform each time I call this library's method or class?

Comment: Figuring that out would require reading through the source code, or, running it under a profiler.  I recommend installing the VS profiler on the machine and profiling the application to see where the bottleneck is